# Does Buddhism allow for true randomness?

Tags: philosophy, pratityasamutpada, reality

Is the law of dependent origination completely deterministic? If everything is dependent, there should be no true randomness. The current mainstream view of the physicists is that true randomness does exist, that is, it is something inherent to the reality, and not just our uncertainty about the current state of the world. In other words, they believe that there is such thing as a true source of randomness. Is this viewpoint incompatible with the Buddhist doctrine? Or does dependent origination allow for some degree of non-determinism?

Comment: Extended discussion in the [**chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30774/discussion-on-question-by-draks-true-randomness-doesnt-exist)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependent origination is not the same as determinism, and is not incompatible with the hypothesis that some things occur truly randomly.

You may take a look at the question about [free will](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/predetermined-future-vs-free-will-in-buddhism) - Buddhism does not say there is no free will. Also the question about [dependent origination and right effort](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/is-there-a-conflict-between-dependent-origination-and-right-effort) may be of use - the following part of the accepted answer shown that it doesn't exclude the possibility of non-determinism:

> When dependent origination is taught in the suttas, often what seems to be stressed are, literally, conditions, not causes as we often understand them (eg. agents that actively produce or directly contribute to a result)